# Union of values in two ranges

Tags: vba, excel

columns indicated I'm trying to create an union of values I have in two ranges from two pivot tables:
[image]

So basically what I want to end up with is for me to have in cell J5 a list of all unique worktypes from both pivot tables (an union of two sets).

I've now created two ranges with all the worktypes (one from each Pivot Table) now I want to end up with a combined list of all unique values from both ranges in cell J5.

Any suggestions?

edit,

I've created an union of two ranges I've created with:

```
Set rUnion = Application.Union(rLeftPivot, rRightPivot)
```

but when I've tried running:

```
rUnion.AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy, _
   CopyToRange:=Range("J5"), Unique:=True
```

I get 1004 error: "Database or table range is not valid", any suggestions?

Comment: I am not sure if I have understood what you want properly: instead of doing selection.Copy (which, apparently, is pasted into A1:A10 and B1:B10), you want to deal with selection as a range?

Comment: what would be in cell J5- a validation list or beginning of the range with all items?

Comment: @verocarbas I've added the second bit of code as an example of what I CAN do just to make it work so these ranges I've added: A1:A10 and B1:B10 can be ignored because in real life they would be replaced with references to  to ranges I'd have created.

Comment: @KezJaw beginning of a list of unique values from both sets I need for further work.

Comment: (my nick name is vArocarbas) I have understood your code. I was asking about what you want to do exactly (talked about the ranges to make my point clear) and still I am not clear on that: you want to avoid the copying by dealing with Selection as a range directly, don't you?

Comment: @varocarbas apologies, yes - instead of a workaround I've proposed i.e. copying two ranges into Excel I would like the whole process to stay within VBA.

Comment: No problem. Do you know that Selection (as any other thing allowing you to copy/paste in VBA) is a range, isn't it? You can do Set iniRange = Intersect... and do with iniRange all the actions you want (or do them with selection directly). You can use this code without copying/pasting at all. iniRange would be rangeFromLeftPivot (or A1:A10)

Comment: You are getting an error because you are not doing it properly. Define iniRange before using it: Dim iniRange As Range. Additionally you don't even need to use iniRange. Selection is a range itself. You can use Selection to prove the point.

Comment: @varocarbas yes you were right and I've deleted my previous comment, I've got it working now but I've run into another: the application.union function I was intending to use doesn't do what I want to do, it just creates another range from two ranges instead of working on values within these ranges, do you have any suggestion as to what I can use instead to achieve what I want to achieve (consolidation of two list which I now have both in ranges)?

Comment: The ranges are the base for anything (the values are just one of the properties of a range); the output of union is a bunch of ranges (= a bunch of cells) you can iterate through them with a loop. If you are not capable to make it working update your question such that it is clearly stated what you want to accomplish. Example: I have two columns with values 1,2,3 and 3,4,5 and I want to write into a third column all the values not contained in both columns: 1, 2, 4, 5.

Comment: @varocarbas I've now rewritten the question as per your advice, thank you for your help.

Comment: I am writing a code for you. But was Intersect working even when copying/pasting? It does a different thing than what you want. Also Union does not make any sense either: it just adds up all the values in both ranges (this is not what you want)

Comment: For applying a filter? Don't do that. Wait a bit and will write a code performing what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there are a lot of possibilities to do that. One of possible answer could be as follows:

```
Dim Rng1 As Range
Dim Rng2 As Range

Set Rng1 = Range("A1:a10")
Set Rng2 = Range("B1:B10")

With Range("J5")
    .Resize(Rng1.Rows.Count, 1) = Rng1.Value
    .Offset(Rng1.Rows.Count, 0).Resize(Rng2.Rows.Count, 1) = Rng2.Value

    'remove duplicates
    Range("J5", .End(xlDown)).RemoveDuplicates 1, xlNo
End With
```

Comment: @KezJaw This works, thank you. Would you be so kind as to provide for me some explanation as to how it works, what does Resize and Offset and xlNo at the very end do?

Comment: `Resize` changes the range size to new one. `Offset` moves range to new position. `.End(xlDown)`- it's code which moves range to new position in the way you do so with `Ctrl + arrays` in excel application. All are `Range modificators` and could be used in any (but logic) combination.